# Is there a bulletproof way to configure your AWS system?

Tags: firewalls, aws

I am learning how to configure a multi-region AWS system. However, everything I read says "if you want/need more security then do X". Why would anyone want less security (is what I start thinking)... Is there a way to create a bullet proof AWS system? If so, what are the key pieces? If not, how can I prove that to someone who asks?

Answer (score 4):

> Why would anyone want less security

Nobody wants less security, but high security usually are also harder and more expensive to maintain, which can also mean having more likelihood for errors. Many companies opt to use simpler system that are less secure than possible because that's good enough for their purpose.

> bullet proof AWS system

There's no such thing as bulletproof system. Security at the infrastructure level is mostly a matter of configuration. Even if the underlying software itself are bug free, you can't beat a system administrator that undermines their security by configuring their firewall to allow any traffic to all machines, and then claim that their system are secure because it has state of the art bug-free firewall.

Answer (score 4):

> Why would anyone want less security

Security has its price. It may be additional services you need to buy, added complexity in a configuration, additional hours spent in maintaining the setup, etc. There always is a point where adding more 'security' (for whatever that may be) does not benefit anymore.

There are also other reasons why security measures are not taken, for example business reasons. For your internal web application for your company, restricting access to known IP addresses may work. For a webshop, not so much.

And even if you would implement all security measurements known (which is impossible, since some would probably conflict), there's still a chance that you make a human error by misconfiguring software, or software you're using has a security bug.

There is no magical checklist which you follow to make everything secure.